# VB + intellisense not working (doesn't show up) + in aspx or html files

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, visual-studio

I have intellisense when i type this:

```
<p><%= boolean.falsestring %></p>
```

I don't have intellisense when i typ this:

```
<p class="<%= boolean.falsestring %>"></p>
```

To further clarify (see line below), the first <%=%> doesn't show me intellisense popup, the second however does, why is that?

```
<p class="<%= boolean.falsestring %>"><%= Boolean.FalseString%></p>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is happening because you are putting tags inside an attribute string.  The code editor in Visual Studio wants to believe that everything inside the double quotes is a string even though it isn't.

There is nothing wrong with your code - it is simply a bug in the Visual Studio code editor.

Answer (score 2):

The reason why is that when you write `<%= %>` inside of a string literal it is counted as a part of the string literal.  It is not counted as an embedded expression.  Hence it is not code and intellisense will not be displayed